# Optimising bagging and boosting classifiers

Tags: r, algorithm, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks at whether or not a person would be successful in getting a loan.

I am running a boosting algorithm, and my goal is to try and optimise it, here is the code:

```
#Boosting
JC.Boost <- boosting(Class ~. , data = JC.train, mfinal=10)
JCpred.boost <- predict.boosting(JC.Boost, newdata=JC.test)
# JCpred.boost
JCBoostpred <- prediction( JCpred.boost$prob[,2], JC.test$Class)
JCBoostperf <- performance(JCBoostpred,"tpr","fpr")
# calc auc (area under curve)
cauc = performance(cpred, "auc")
print(as.numeric(cauc@y.values))
```

How does one go about optimising their algorithm so that the AUC is higher? I know it's a silly million dollar question, but I'm a bit confused with where to start.

I have tried increasing `mfinal` which has increased the AUC value, but I'm stuck after that. Any ideas would help.

P.S. the code for boosting is pretty much the same

Comment: Any other hyper-parameters to change? Any variables you can transform? Any feature engineering?

Comment: These are all good stepping stones, I will get back to you with more questions.